# How to run a JavaScript file - V8

Tags: c++, v8

I have embedded v8 into my c++ application. Referring https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/samples/hello-world.cc I am  able to run a javascript. Tested and works fine.

I access the links from my c++ application, download html data, download javascript. Some embedded scripts in the html call functions in external script files. How do I ensure that the external scripts are available for the embedded ones?

The downloaded JavaScript files (one or more) may be of large size. In such a context, how do I execute the JavaScript api present in HTML using v8? Code to run a JavaScript in v8 is below,

```
  // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
  v8::Local<v8::String> source =
      v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "'Hello' + ', World!'",
                              v8::NewStringType::kNormal)
          .ToLocalChecked();
  // Compile the source code.
  v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
      v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();
  // Run the script to get the result.
  v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();
```

Assuming downloaded javascript is 200KB, how can I feed such a large buffer to  v8::Script::Compile api. And when I have more than one file present, how can feed I them to v8 ?

Comment: All you have presented is an excerpt from the v8 samples, there is no indication of an attempt to load external files here? I imagine the process is the same, read to string, compile with the same context, and run them?

Comment: I am just looking at the way, shall I store the received javascript as files and pass the file to V8 or as I receive partial jsvascript in HTTP packets (chunks) can I pass the partial javascript to V8.

Comment: Assuming javascript is of  100KB or more, do I need to pass it as string? Or what happens if we have more than 1 javascripts downloaded. These are actually stopping confusing me and kind of stuck.

Comment: I don't understand why you are worried about 100kB allocations when computers have gigabytes of RAM. Strings are stored in the heap so in thoery, only limited by the virtual memory exposed by your OS. JavaScript is plain text so yeah you have to load it through one of those readers. Maybe v8 supports reading from a file stream or a byte buffer, you should look at the api docs for that. One "easy" and sure hack you can do is concatenate all the files into a single string and parse it.

Comment: It's almost like you are re-implementing a browser at this point. What's your use case? Have you considered using headless chrome over the c++ api? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rlqcp8nk-ZQvldNJWdbaMbwfDbJoOXvahPCDoPGOwhQ/edit#heading=h.ng2bxb15li9a

Comment: It is a existing c++ application. Headless chrome is not an option for me at this point of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a Javascript function from V8 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062300/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-v8-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I ensure that the external scripts are available for the embedded ones?

You load the external scripts first.

> How do I execute the JavaScript API present in HTML using v8?

Do you mean the DOM? `window`, `document` and the like? The DOM is not part of ECMAScript, so V8 knows nothing about it; it is provided by the embedder (i.e. usually Chrome). In your own embedding you need to provide all those objects yourself, using V8's API. Needless to say, this is a *huge* amount of work. If what you're after is a way to render websites, then I recommend that you use some existing component/library for that, for example the Chromium Embedded Framework, or your favorite GUI toolkit's WebView (or whatever it is called).

> Assuming downloaded JavaScript is 200KB, how can I feed such a large buffer to v8::Script::Compile API?

Just like you feed a small script to V8: put it into a `v8::Local<v8::String>`, then call `v8::Script::Compile` and `v8::Script::Run`.

> And when I have more than one file present, how can feed I them to v8 ?

Call `v8::Script::Compile` and `v8::Script::Run` repeatedly, possibly using a loop. For an example, see V8's [shell sample](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/master/samples/shell.cc), specifically the function `RunMain`.

> As I receive partial JavaScript in HTTP packets (chunks), can I pass the partial JavaScript to V8?

Yes, V8 has a script streaming interface. See the API documentation for `v8::ScriptCompiler::ExternalSourceStream`. For examples on how to use it, you can study the [tests](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/master/test/cctest/parsing/test-scanner-streams.cc). Streaming may or may not be worth it for scripts as small as 200KB; it is definitely not required.

Comment: Your answer looks very helpful to me. I will explore and revert back.

Comment: Is there any simple example for how to use v8::ScriptCompiler::ExternalSourceStream

Comment: V8's own tests for it (see the link in my post) are probably the easiest example. As I wrote, using streaming is not required; if you want to optimize for simplicity, then just don't stream, use a `String`.

Comment: I am able to execute javascript using V8. I got into issues most valgrind memory leaks and invalid access. I will post that query in a separate question.