# How to call a Javascript function from V8 in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

To run a simple Javascript program using v8 I go about it as follows:

```
// Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "'Hello' + ', from Javascript!'", v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();

// Compile the source code.
v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

// Run the script to get the result.
v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();
```

How can I go about calling a Javascript function in a **/path/to/my_js_functions.js** file?

```
function myJsFunction(stringParam) {
  return stringParam   // The function returns a stringParam from the parameter
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to get your hands on the function object. Assuming it's in the global scope (== on the global object), you can access it like this:

```
v8::Local<v8::String> name = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(
    isolate, "myJsFunction", v8::NewStringType::kInternalized).ToLocalChecked();
v8::Local<v8::Value> obj =
    context->Global()->Get(context.local(), name).ToLocalChecked();
if (!obj->IsFunction()) {
  /* someone overwrote it, handle error */
}
v8::Local<v8::Function> my_function = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(obj);
```

Note that every time you get a `MaybeLocal`, the result could be empty, which happens when an exception was thrown. If you can't guarantee that that won't happen, then you shouldn't just use `.ToLocalChecked()` (which will crash when the `MaybeLocal` is empty), but instead properly check for and handle the error case.

Once you have a function, you can prepare arguments for it and call it:

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> receiver = ...;
int argc = ...;
v8::Local<v8::Value> args[argc] = ...;
v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> result = my_function->Call(context.local(), receiver, argc, args);
```

Again, the result is a `MaybeLocal`, because functions can throw exceptions (explicitly, or indirectly by calling/doing something that throws). It's up to you to catch any error cases, and otherwise `Cast` the result to the appropriate type and do something with it.

(Working with JavaScript through a C++ API is not exactly pleasant. That's largely due to the many conceptual differences between the two languages.)

For many more examples, have a look at V8's [test-api.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/test/cctest/test-api.cc).

Comment: Thank you very much @jmrk for the answer. I have looked at [test-api.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/test/cctest/test-api.cc). I am, however, not sure as to how to go about loading the js file. Could you please suggest how to go about it? I've been at this for a few days now. There doesn't seem to be much documentation about it. If you could please help with an illustration of how the code would flow. Again, thank you.

Comment: Open the file any way you want (using standard C++ facilities), read its content as a string, create a `v8::String` from it and pass it to `v8::Script::Compile` and `Run` like in the snippet you posted. If you want to study an example: here's how the `d8` shell implements its `load` command: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/d8/d8.cc?dr&q=shell::load

Comment: Thank you @jmrk. I can't express my gratitude enough. It works! Thank you for your help again.